# Logging dictConfig does not work with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

My problem is: Python logging configuration is not working using configuration file and multiprocessing.

I'm using python2.7.

## Example

Here my **example.py**:

```
import json
import logging
import logging.config
import multiprocessing


def get_logger():
    with open("logging.conf") as fd:
        config_json_obj = json.load(fd)
    #logging.config.dictConfig(config_json_obj)
    logging.basicConfig(filename="my.log", level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    return logger

def funSquare(num):
    logger = get_logger()
    # write logging info from process
    logger.info(num ** 2)
    return num ** 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = get_logger()

    logger.info("Start program")
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = pool.map(funSquare, range(10))
    print(results)
```

And here my **logging.conf** file:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "formatters":
  {
    "simple":
    {
      "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    },
    "verbose":
    {
      "format": "%(asctime)s %(thread)s %(levelname)s %(module)s [-] %(message)s"
    }
  },
  "handlers":
  {
    "console":
    {
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "formatter": "simple",
      "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
    },
    "file":
    {
      "class": "logging.FileHandler",
      "formatter": "verbose",
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "filename": "mylog.log"
    }
  },
  "loggers":
  {
    "Main":
    {
      "level": "INFO",
      "handlers": ["console", "file"],
      "propagate": 0
    }
  },
  "root":
  {
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "handlers": ["file"]
  }
}
```

At this point, example.py is working. You will get in my.log file logging lines from both main program and new processes.

## Reproduce my problem

Now, if I replace lines:

```
#logging.config.dictConfig(config_json_obj)
logging.basicConfig(filename="my.log", level=logging.INFO)
```

By

```
logging.config.dictConfig(config_json_obj)
#logging.basicConfig(filename="my.log", level=logging.INFO)
```

In my.log file you will see logging lines only from main program, not from processes.

Now my questions:

1. Why this is happening?
2. What is the solution?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't expect writing from multiple process into a single file to work (it may work in some situations, but can't be guaranteed). The correct way is to use a multiprocessing `Queue` and have all the file writing done by a single process, as outlined in [this blog post](https://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/using-logging-with-multiprocessing.html) from 2010 (too long to reproduce here). The important thing is that each process configures logging *after* it's created. You could adapt the linked example to use `dictConfig` rather than the programmatic configuration shown in the example, if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `__name__` will evaluate `'__main__'`; you need to

- either: rename `"Main"` in your config file to `"__main__"` (for the name of the logger)
- or (maybe more robust): `logger = logging.getLogger('Main')` in your main file

the logger you are getting with `logging.getLogger(__name__)` is not configured otherwise.

Comment: hiro, thanks, your solution works for me. However, what do you think about comment from @Vinay?

Comment: i totally agree with his comment. you will have race conditions that may cause problmes...a `Queue` is an excellent solution! there may be others. this may help https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes (have a look at who the author is...)

Answer (score 0):

In logging.DictConfig, the root logger is defined by "". Thus in your dictionnary, you should use:

```
"":
{
  "level": "DEBUG",
  "handlers": ["file"]
}
```

to properly set the root logger (and in the .ini file, you use "root", don't ask me why)